# Creating an ubuntu live USB for an appliance with no video adapter

Tags: grub2, serial-port, headless

I have an appliance for which I do not know the root password - and I can't access the GRUB menu ( I tried <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>,<kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> ). This appliance doesn't have any video adapter - only a serial connection.

I was thinking of booting it with a live USB disk, mounting the appliance disk and then changing the root password (for instance by changing `/etc/passwd`).

The issue I face, is that I created a live USB using Ubuntu startup disk utility which boots perfectly when used on my laptop, but when it is connected to the appliance, I do not see the console via the serial port.

(Note that when booting the appliance normally, and not from the live USB disk, I see the console properly).